# Firing off Google Analytics from C# does not work

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I have the following code that I have in C# but I'm not seeing anything come through on Fiddler2?  I've looked at many questions on here and in general although there seems to be different ways of doing it.  I need my MVC controller to redirect the user onto a third party page after firing off tracking to Google Analytics.

**C# code**

```
var rnd = new Random();
var statsRequest = string.Format("http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.6.5&utmn={0}&utmcs=-&utmsc=-&utmul={1}&utmje=-&utmfl=-&utmdt=&utmhid=&utmr=0&utmp=&utmac={2}&utmcc=__utma%3D", 
    rnd.Next(100000000, 999999999), 
    languageCode, 
    accountId);

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadData(statsRequest);
}
```

Can anyone please help?  If I run this code in a unit test it works (i.e. I see the statsRequest in Fiddler2) but not when I hit the webpage.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

The above code is wrapped in a method that the controller action calls

**C# MVC Controller**

```
public class MyController  ...
{
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        SendGoogleTrackingCode();
        Response.Redirect(externalUrl);
    }
}
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the running code is not waiting for the GA request to send it before your redirect. 
Try to add some exception handler to check what kind of issues are raising.

But, your GA hit data is a little outdated.

GA hit data shoud be built using Measurement Protocol.
Take a look at the official docs here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide

You can try build a custom hit using Hit Builder at:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/

Also you can check if the hit is valid using their debugger params:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits

Besides that, to fire it from C#, there's a couple of methods. Firstly, take a look at this example:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["v"] = "1";
    data["tid"] = "UA-XXXXXXXX-1"; 
    data["cid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    data["t"] = "event";
    data["ec"] = "myCategory";
    data["ea"] = "myAction";
    var url = @"https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect";
    var response = wb.UploadValues(url, data);
    var stringResponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```

Also, I've found an useful wrapper for doing this at:
https://gist.github.com/0liver/11229128

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for this, should the parameters in the namevaluecollection correspond to the querystring parameters I'm guessing?  I.e I need to change the v, tid, cid, t, etc etc.. to utmsc, utmul etc..  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I'm actually running the code in debug so I'm holding the code on the line below the DownloadData(webRequest) so I don't think it's a not waiting problem..(?)

Comment: Jamie, the v, tid, cid, t are actually the official parameters :) The Measurement Protocol use them as they are, so you dont need to change the parameters before sending...

Comment: Sure, It doesn't look like a waiting problem. Just try with the new code and print out the response to check if it's sending before the redirect....